# How to remove an orphan site collection in the SharePoint (2010) config DB?

Tags: 2010, powershell, stsadm

An error occurred when trying to create a site collection with my `PowerShell` script and now I'm unable to delete this site collection in order to try again.

It appears that I've got an orphaned site collection right now which only seems to exist in the config DB and not in the content DB. I can locate the site collection in the `SiteMap` table of my `config DB`, but not in the `AllWebs` table of the content DB.

I've tried several solutions without success like:

```
stsadm -o deletesite -force -siteid {guid} -databaseserver {server} -databasename {name}
```

But usually this fails with the response that there is no site collection with the specified ID (again since the site doesn't seem to exist in the content DB).

Any ideas how to delete the site collection from the config DB?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3837.how-to-identify-and-clean-up-orphan-sites-and-orphan-contentdatabases-in-sharepoint.aspx

Please let me know if this works.